# Can data be read during upload in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Imagine that Mr. XYZ are uploading a file of 500MB into Hadoop (HDFS). 100MB of data is successfully uploaded into Hadoop(HDFS) and Mr. ABC as a client wants to read the uploaded data while the upload is still in progress. What will happen in such a scenario, will the 1000 MB of data that is uploaded will it be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.
If one is uploading a file of 500MB into the HDFS. If 100MB of data has been successfully uploaded in the HDFS and the other client is about to read the uploaded data while the upload is still to be in progress. Then what will happen? Whether that 100MB of data which is uploaded will be displayed or not?
The default block-size of Hadoop1x is 64MB and of Hadoop2x is 128MB.

Let the block-size be 100MB, i.e., five blocks are to replicated three times (the default replication-factor)

Below procedure describes how the block is to be write in the HDFS:

If we have A, B, C, D and E be the five blocks for client, file, name-node and data-node. Then firstly, the client takes the Block A and approaches the name-node for the data-node location in order to store this current block and replicated copies of it. Once the data-node information is available to the client, he will reach directly to the data-node and starts the copying of Block A, which will at the same time gets replicated to second data-node. When the block gets copied and replicated to data-node, the confirmation of Block A storage will get to the client, then further, the client will re-start the same procedure for the next block i.e., Block B.

Thus, if one is uploading a file of 500MB into the HDFS where 100MB of data has been successfully uploaded in the HDFS and the other client is about to read the uploaded data while the upload is still to be in progress then only the present block which is being written will not be visible to the readers.